# mean of random variables

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, probability-theory, stochastic-processes

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ be a probability space, $X : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a discrete random variable and $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ a random variable.

I can't demonstrate that $E(g(X)) = \underset{t}{\sum} g(t) \mathbb{P}(X = t)$.

Thank you!

Comment: g is a function you mean, not a random variable :)

Comment: in my paper is written that g is a random variable...maybe it is a mistake

Comment: hmmm then I cannot help you. Otherwise (if g is a function), this is known as the law of unconscious statistician and a proof in two steps can be found here: (http://www.google.gr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCEQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmath.arizona.edu%2F~tgk%2F464_10%2Fchap2_9_7.pdf&ei=2DZmVL6RFNDwaMWlgfAH&usg=AFQjCNFiTa2m5wK01rwAtHmvuvbO_cWiqw&bvm=bv.79400599,d.d2s)

Comment: a, ok if it is a mistake, then take a look in the link, theorem 3.

Comment: You are welcome :)!

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it just the definition of expectation. Because $X$ is a discrete random variable, you will need to sum over all possible values that $X$ can have:

$$E(g(X)) = \sum _{X=t} g(X=t) p(X=t)$$

Comment: No this is not just the definition of expectation. As mentioned in the comments 5 hours ago, this is a theorem often called the law of unconscious statistician.